# Освобождение памяти в структуре

Tags: c++

Когда читал про выделение памяти с помощью new  и ее освобождения, возник вопрос. Вот пример кода:

```
const int size_m = 40;    

int main ()
{   
  struct car
  {
     char *name;
  };

  int QCar;
  cout << "How many car?";
  cin >> QCar;
  car *pCar = new car[QCar];
  for ( int i = 0; i < QCar; i++)
  {
     cout << "Car name: ";
     char temp [size_m];
     char >> temp;
     char *ptemp = new char [strlen(temp)+1];
     strcpy(ptemp,temp);
     pCar[i].name = ptemp;
  }
  cout << " Your auto"<< endl;
  for ( int i = 0; i < QCar; i++)
  {
     cout << pCar[i].name;
  }
  delete []pCar;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
 }
```

Является ли достаточным только это освобождение или нужно еще. Или вообще иначе. Просто выделение памяти дважды , а удаление одно.

Comment: Я изначально пробывал , как советовал @Kirill21 и@ Wanket, но результат некорректен, поскольку в дальнейшем я опираюсь на удаленный адрес. Когда просматриваю последний цикл for.

Comment: Добавьте деструктор, где удаляйте динамически выделенную память под name

Comment: Честно говоря, не очень понял, как реализовать это

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Почти правильно :) Сейчас поясню, почему "почти".

В C++ у каждого объекта есть такая вешь, как конструктор и деструктор. Если их не написать самому - их сгенерирует компилятор (все несколько сложнее, но я упрощаю как только могу). Деструктор вызывается при уничтожении объекта, так что вот тут

```
delete []pCar;
```

он будет вызван. Но вы не написали свой деструктор, а генерируемый понятия не имеет, что делать с `name` и потому не делает ничего. Так что надо дописать свой деструктор -

```
struct car
{ 
    char *name;
    ~car() { delete[]name; }
};
```

В таком случае будет достаточно написать ваш `delete []pCar;` - и все будет корректно. Почти. Почему почти? потому что а вдруг вы забудете инициализировать `name`? И он будет показывать непонятно куда, а при удалении непонятно чего произойти может все, что угодно. Поэтому давайте допишем конструктор

```
car(): name(nullptr) {}
```

И все бы ничего, но ведь кто-то может (может, даже вы) написать где-то `pCar->name = "ПЦ"`. И при попытке освобождения будут неприятности. Поэтому лучше делать не структуру, а класс:

```
struct car
{ 
  public:
    car(): name(nullptr) {}
    ~car() { delete[]name; }
  private:
    char *name;
};
```

Готово? Почти. Потому что надо еще как-то теперь заставить `name` хранить строку. Опять же, делаем конструктор

```
car(const char * str):name(nullptr) {
    if (str) {
        name = new char[strlen(str)+1];
        strcpy(name,str);
    }
}
```

и функцию-член для обращения к этой строке:

```
const char* str() const { return name; }
```

и оператор присваивания, чтоб `name` менять:

```
car& operator=(const char * str)
{ 
    delete[]name;
    if (str)
    {
        name = new char[strlen(str)+1];
        strcpy(name,str);
    } else name = nullptr;
}
```

Вот теперь можно считать готово. Можно дописать еще многое, но главное - уже на месте:

```
struct car
{ 
  public:
    car(const char * str = nullptr):name(nullptr) {
        if (str) {
            name = new char[strlen(str)+1];
            strcpy(name,str);
        }
    }
    ~car() { delete[]name; }
    const char str() const { return name; }
    car& operator=(const char * str)
    { 
        delete[]name;
        if (str)
        {
            name = new char[strlen(str)+1];
            strcpy(name,str);
        } else name = nullptr;
    }
  private:
    char *name;
};
```

А ваш код превращается в

```
car *pCar = new car[QCar];
for ( int i = 0; i < QCar; i++)
{
     cout << "Car name: ";
     char temp [size_m];
     char >> temp;
     pCar[i] = temp;
}
cout << " Your auto"<< endl;
for ( int i = 0; i < QCar; i++)
{
   cout << pCar[i].str();
}
delete []pCar;
```

Примерно так - но только для начала :)

Comment: Возможно, стоит 0 заменить на nullptr?

Comment: @AndrewRomanov Судя по коду, автор только начинает изучать азы языка. И я не уверен, что он изучает сразу C++11, поэтому в дебри не лезу. Конечно, лучше, но тут есть много чего лучше :) Это же просто учебный код...

Comment: @Harry несовсем азы, код написан, как быстрый пример, чтобы людям проще было изложить точку зрения)

Comment: @Funnyjoco Тогда смело меняйте нули на `nullptr` :)

Comment: Ну или воспользоваться стандартным задефайненным `NULL`, если уж не _C++11_.

Comment: Все, уговорили, поменял! :)

Comment: Отличный ответ! <зануда_mode>Но оператор = не готов к самоприсваиванию.</зануда_mode>

Comment: @VladD <отмазка>Да я и так замахался по клавишам стучать</отмазка>... :)

Comment: Главное, о чем забыли это "правило трёх". И оператор присваивания следует сделать принимающим `const car&`, а не сишную строку. Так и дублирование кода можно (и нужно) исключить. В общем, усилия, бесспорно, были приложены, но в ответе слишком много дыр. Но если все дыры закрывать, это уже будет ответ о том как сделать свой велосипедный класс строки.

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном коде есть две сущности, память под которые выделяется динамически: массив `car` и для каждого `car` - `name`. Необходимо освобождать память, выделенную и для того, и для другого.
В текущем варианте освобождается память, выделенная для массива `car`. Память, выделенная для названий автомобилей не освобождается. Сделать это можно, например, так:

```
for (int i = 0; (i < QCar); ++i) {
    delete[] pCar[i].name;
}
delete[] pCar;
```

Однако, - для снижения вероятности ошибок и для освобождения памяти при возникновении исключений, - лучше было бы автоматизировать этот процесс: применить интеллектуальные указатели или создать свои классы с освобождающими память деструкторами (а для `name` можно использовать `string`).

Comment: Да, я как вы делал, но по отладчику несмог точно понять прав я или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Исключительно о том как добавить деструктор в Car:

```
struct car
 {
 char *name;

 car()//для чистоты
 :name(nullptr)
 {}
 ~car()
 {
     delete name;
  }
};
```

А так же неплохо бы ещё и конструктор копирования, так как вы храните указатель на область памяти, которую стоит копировать при копировании объекта.

А если пройтись по коду, то многое не правильно (об указателе на внешнюю по отношению к классу car память понятно -- нарушение инкапсуляции).
Относительно переменной temp:
Это указатель на массив данных, который создаётся в стеке итерации цикла, при этом далее вы туда копируете данные, потом этот указатель приравниваете к внутренней переменной car. После итерации цикла память (та, на которую указывала переменная *temp*) и *name* указывает в никуда -- падение при доступе или когда-то, зависит от содержимого.
Так же не освобождается переменная ptemp ([strcpy](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strcpy) копируется не указатель, а содержимое). -- утечка памяти.

Используйте для строк [std::string](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), замечательный класс, который умеет всё, что вам нужно (управление памятью, копирование, разделение памяти и т.д.)

Comment: `delete` проверяет на 0 сам, проверка не нужна.

Comment: не знал, спасибо за информацию, посмотрю, поправлю :)

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < QCar; i++)
{
    cout << "Car name: ";
    char temp[size_m];
    //char >> temp;
    char *ptemp = new char[strlen(temp) + 1];
    strcpy(ptemp, temp);
    pCar[i].name = ptemp;
    delete[]ptemp;
}
```

Comment: Вы  создаете на каждой итерации временный  динамический массив. Он нужен лишь во время итерации, значит как она завершается вы должны последним действием удалить ненужную более память, что бы выделить ее на следующей итерации без утечки.

Comment: А в `pCar[i].name` после удаления `ptemp` тогда что будет?

Comment: @Pavel Parshin - да, вы правы, написал не думая, ваша идея с деструктором является правильной.

Answer (score -1):

C pCar все правильно, а вот очистить ptemp забыли.

```
pCar[i].name = ptemp;
delete[] ptemp
```

Comment: А в `pCar[i].name` после удаления `ptemp` тогда что будет?